# How do I restrict an auto-generated route to accept only POST requests?

Tags: php, symfony, post, routes, sonata

We have overridden Sonata's `RegistrationController` using Easy Extends. In our generated `appDevProjectContainerUrlMatcher` class, we now have the following lines:

```
        if ($pathinfo === '/password/reset') {
            return array (  '_controller' => 'Application\\Sonata\\UserBundle\\Controller\\RegistrationController::passwordResetAction',  '_route' => 'fos_user_password_reset',);
        }
```

I am able to open my customized `RegistrationController` class and see the following:

```
/**
 * @return RedirectResponse
 */
public function passwordResetAction()
{
...
}
```

**Now the question: I want to make this action only accept POST requests. How do I do that if there is no route annotation already present?** (I can't find anywhere where this route is being explicitly defined, excluding the auto-generated class mentioned above.)

===

Edit: This is in a Symfony 2.7 application.

Comment: which symfony version  ?

Comment: This is Symfony 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can verify if it's a Post request like :

```
if ($request->isMethod('post')) { //    Uppercase request method:POST
    // your code
}
```

[the symfony 2.7 doc said](https://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html)

> getMethod() Gets the request "intended" method.

may be you can try this also :

```
$request->getMethod()
```